# Hidden input isn't hidden in Laravel blade template

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm trying to make hidden input and set some value in blade template but it isn't hidden and is visible on the page. This is the field

```
{{ Form::hidden('price', '<?php echo $item['price'] * $item['quantity'];?>') }}
```

I have tried without `<?php ?>` tags because as I read everything in `{{ }}` in blade templates is read like php.. so this

```
{{ Form::hidden('price', '$item['price'] * $item['quantity']') }}
```

Throw error

> 'syntax error, unexpected 'price' (T_STRING)'

Comment: got this `'syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is `'$item['price'] * $item['quantity']'`.

1. You have single quotes within single quotes without them being escaped so that will result in an error
2. PHP will evaluate this as a string instead of the expression that you want.  There is no need to wrap this expression in quotes.

So in Blade 4, you will want:

```
{{ Form::hidden('price', $item['price'] * $item['quantity']) }}
```

**Blade version 5 only**

In Blade 5, `{!! !!}` should be used for HTML code.

```
{!! Form::hidden('price', $item['price'] * $item['quantity']) !!}
```

Comment: It's visible on the page.. This is what I see on the page `{!! Form::hidden('price', $item['price'] * $item['quantity']) !!}`

Comment: Oh, nevermind about the last sentence, you're using version 4.  `{{ }}` on 4 is equivalent to `{!! !!}` on 5.

Comment: Finally. Thank's for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```html
{{ Form::hidden('price', '$item["price"] * $item["quantity"]') }}
```

Quotes and double quotes might be the solution

Comment: Like this I got text field on the page and in view source this `<input name="price" type="hidden" value="$item[&quot;price&quot;] * $item[&quot;quantity&quot;]">`

Comment: Oh.. that was not expected, @Devon must be right then